# Java Number format

Tags: java, numbers, format, number-formatting

I have some double, I did format them with

```
Locale loc = new Locale("hu", "HU");
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(loc);
```

now my doubles looks like this: 1 432,321, How can i format them to looks like this: 1 432,3 , any idea?

Comment: is this rather formatting or rounding?

Comment: just formatting but if it's possible rounding will be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `setMaximumFractionDigits` method on the `NumberFormat`.

```
Locale loc = new Locale("hu", "HU");
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(loc);
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);
```

Then your output is "1 432,3"

This will round whatever the input is to the correct number of digits. So, for example, 2.35 will be formatted as "2,4"